# Nearby API for RN

Tags: react-native, google-nearby

I am building an app that needs to know the closes users that also have the app.  I have been told that Nearby API is the best solution for this, I am hoping to build my app in React Native, does Nearby API work for RN?

Thanks for your help

Comment: nearby API only works on the local network and you have to make a native version for this in RN.

Comment: We've put together [react-native-nearby-api](https://github.com/badfeatures/react-native-nearby-api) exactly for this need ourselves. Check it out if you still need it!

Answer (score 1):

React-native doesn't have Nearby API in its core, but [you could wrap native code in a manager](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.36/docs/native-modules-ios.html#native-modules) or take a look at [react-native-invoke](https://github.com/wix/react-native-invoke), you can:

> Invoke any native code directly from Javascript in React Native
>   (without wrapping it first with a native manager)

Alternatively, you can use this approach **if you have the coordinates of the other users and you want to check if they are nearby**:

You can get the user location with [Geolocation API](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.36/docs/geolocation.html#geolocation)

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    myLocation = position.coords
  },
  error => alert(error),
  { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000*60*5 })
```

Then you could calculate the distance between the user and places (if you have their coordinates) using this function:

```
export const calculateDistance = (place, me)=>{
const toRadians = (angle)=>{
    return angle * Math.PI / 180
}
let lat1 = place.latitude
let lon1 = place.longitude
let lat2 = me.latitude
let lon2 = me.longitude

var R = 6371e3; // metres
var phi1 = toRadians(lat1)
var phi2 = toRadians(lat2)
var deltaPhi = toRadians((lat2-lat1))
var deltaLambda = toRadians((lon2-lon1))

var a = Math.sin(deltaPhi/2) * Math.sin(deltaPhi/2) +
        Math.cos(phi1) * Math.cos(phi2) *
        Math.sin(deltaLambda/2) * Math.sin(deltaLambda/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
return d}
```

Credits: [Movable Type Scripts](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: thanks I will look at the native wrapper, the main point of Nearby is that you dont have to get peoples location as Nearby uses a lot of very low battery and data tools to find nearby including sound waves of all things